# Android send mail

Tags: android, android-layout

In the following main.xml i have a edittext,my question is how to onclick of send mail button how to send a mail where the To address is hardcoded always..

```
 mail.setOnClickListener(

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       //How to sendmail to adress someadress@xx.com oblibk of send mail button

    });

     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <EditText android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <requestFocus></requestFocus>
      </EditText>
      <Button android:text="Send Mail" android:id="@+id/mail" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
      <Button android:text="Back" android:id="@+id/back2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>


   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);     
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");     
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youraddress@aaaaa.com"});     
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, yourSubject);     
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, yourBodyText);     
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: I would use `Intent.setType("message/rfc822")` instead

Comment: But this would start a new activity right..?I dont want this way..on click of the button the message should be mailed

Comment: It will open up the user's mail application. They can send the mail from there, and then they will be returned to your activity. This is the correct way of doing things. It seems you are trying to reinvent the wheel. You do not need to have the `EditText` for the user to type in. This should be done in the user's email app.

Comment: Added message/rfc822. Still offers: googledrive,ftp,gmail,skype.