# How to set the subject in default email client in android?

Tags: android

I have set the default email as in code as,

```
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "support@example.com" });
```

I have to set the subject too, when i tried to set Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT but I didnt get this .

Could someone help me on this.

Comment: emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"From Android App");

Answer (score 5):

[This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973827/android-send-mail/6973840#6973840) my earlier post and it works fine, take a look on it.

Here's the code in your case:

`email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject here");`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The acutal line that interest you is :

```
emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, yourSubject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope it will help

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
```